# What does the phrase "grooving down the street" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "grooving down the street" in the following sentence from the description of the game Giant Dancing Plushies:

> Swipe along with melodious beats to keep massive giant teddy bears and
> cute bunnies **grooving down the street**.

I know the [lexical meanings of the word "groove"](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/groove) but I am not sure which of them fits here.

Here is a brief description of the game from [148 Apps](https://www.148apps.com/reviews/giant-dancing-plushies-review/):

> Giant Dancing Plushies is a game where you control building-sized
> stuffed animals as they strut down the street, destroying cars, tanks,
> and more. You can move these giant animals one step at a time, but the
> game challenges you to do it to the beat of either the in-game
> soundtrack or whatever music you might be listening to at the time.

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question. And meaning #5 in your dictionary link is the correct one. Does it not make sense? The dictionary's example sentence is similar.

Comment: What bad writing. Grooving down the street should mean enjoying themselves as they dance down the street. Yet, they are destructive. What the heck do these developers think, anyway?

Comment: @TypeIA Thank you for pointing this out. As a non-native speaker, I find it a bit tricky to figure out the meaning. Thanks to your help, I get the sense of the sentence now.

Comment: @Lambie I don't see "grooving" as necessarily incompatible with destructiveness. Do you have any teenagers in your town?

Comment: cute bunnies grooving down the street is incompatible with: destroying cars, tanks, and more. The **discourse** does not work.

Comment: @Lambie you're correct that "grooving" and destructiveness don't usually go together. The writer is telling us that, in the game, they do. I would expect to see cute stuffed animals dancing down the street, casually crushing cars, not realizing what they're doing. Sounds like that's the game's joke.

Answer (score 1):

All of the following are equivalent:

- Make sure that the giant teddy bears keep on **grooving** down the street.
- Make sure that the giant teddy bears keep on **continue unimpeded** down the street.
- Make sure that the giant teddy bears keep on **traveling** down the street **unmolested**
- Make sure that the giant teddy bears keep on **going** down the street.

In American English, "keep on grooving" means:

- I hope that resume what you were doing before you were stopped
- do not let other people stop you
- do not give-up
- keep going
- persevere in the face of your obstacles
- continue as you were
- continue what you were doing a little while ago.